# How to regroup multiple transactions in 1

Tags: transactions, json

How can I send 2 transactions in 1 operation ?
Can I just chain them in my JSON like

```
"contents":
    [{"kind": "transaction", (...)},
    {"kind": "transaction", (...)}]
```

How to manage the counters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just need to increment the counter. Here's an example in C#: https://netezos.dev/docs/get-started.html#forge-an-operation